# how to configure connection string for linq when we upload site to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I uploaded my site through FTP. It show invalid object error.I think it may be due to connection string.Please any bode help me to configure linq as database.My database is ready and code too but due to connection problem my site is not working.

Comment: Linq is not a database. But with this amount of information we need super natural gifts to help you.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to change the following in the `web.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Datamodel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Datamodel.csdl|res://*/Datamodel.ssdl|res://*/Datamodel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=<IP_ADDRESS_OF_DATABASE>;initial catalog=<DATABASE_NAME>;persist security info=True;user id=<LOGIN_USER>;password=<LOGIN_PASSWORD>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Check if IP_ADDRESS_OF_DATABASE field is *localhost*. If so; you'll need to change it. If your `database` has moved and ip address has changed, you will need to modify aswell

Answer (score 0):

connection string is usually stored in web.config file, specially when you use default database handling objects such as SQLDataSource, uploading a web site on FTP, means your existing connection string is looking for a particular sever name, id, password on a server (and not on your local PC), so you should talk to the hosting persons or check the information they have already provided, for how to setup a database, then you will need to modify the web.config file for proper connection string. The procedure is same if your connections string is some where else, one additional step is to recompile the project after modifying it.